# What, exactly, is eager execution from a programming point of view?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to understand eager execution. Pages returned by Google describe what it does for you, and I'm ok with that. I am trying to understand it from the point of view of program code. Here is an example from [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/eager-execution-tensorflow-8042128ca7be).

```
a = tf.constant([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

The article says this statement does something different depending on whether you are in eager mode or not. Without eager mode, print(a) gives:

```
Tensor("Const:0", shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32)
```

With eager mode, print(a) gives:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1 2]
 [3 4]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32)
```

Please could someone explain what these two return values are. If they are two different object types, a Tensor and a tf.Tensor, what is the difference between these objects?

I have searched the TensorFlow documentation and can't see anything that addresses this distinction. Any pointers gratefully received.

Thanks,

Julian

Answer (score 1):

Lazy execution delays evaluation as much as possible. In context of TensorFlow, it will create a plan of execution (a graph) before it does anything, then when everything is ready, it will feed the input into the graph and calculate everything to return the output. `tf.constant` creates an execution node in the graph that will receive a constant value when the execution starts. You can compare lazy evaluation to a Rube Goldberg machine: you build the whole thing, then you drop a marble into it and watch the magic unfold.

Eager execution evaluates immediately. In context of TensorFlow, it does not create a graph. `tf.constant` creates a constant, with a certain value, right then and there. If compared to the Rube Goldberg machine, you could imagine building the first part of the machine, drop the marble in, then stop it when the marble exits, before building the next part of the machine, and reintroducing the marble with the same position and velocity. :P

TensorFlow is much more efficient in the lazy evaluation mode, but the eager mode is easier to develop and debug on.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I still don't understand what Tensor and tf.Tensor are. Your explanation suggests Tensor is an "execution" node and tf.Tensor is a tensor. But that isn't clear from the TensorFlow documentation.